# How to use a returned value outside an operator/tasks

Tags: amazon-web-services, airflow, mwaa

I have a dag like the one below and i need to use the value returned from a python operator outside the tasks. How do i achieve this?

```
dag = DAG(
    dag_id='example_batch_submit_job',
    schedule_interval=None,
    start_date=datetime(2022, 7, 27),
    tags=['batch_job'],
    catchup=False)

def get_inputs(**kwargs):
    num_jobs = kwargs['dag_run'].conf['num_jobs']
    return num_jobs

run_this = PythonOperator(
    task_id='get_input',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=get_inputs,
    dag=DAG,
)

jobs = num_jobs <------ How do i pass the returned value here
for job in jobs:
    submit_batch_job = BatchOperator(
        task_id=f'submit_batch_job_{job}',
        job_name=JOB_NAME,
        job_queue=JOB_QUEUE,
        job_definition=JOB_DEFINITION,
        parameters={}
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Airflow<2.3.0

```
@task
def make_list(count):
    context = get_current_context()
    for i in range(count):
        t = BatchOperator(
            task_id=f"submit_batch_job_{i}",
            job_name=JOB_NAME,
            job_queue=JOB_QUEUE,
            job_definition=JOB_DEFINITION,
            parameters={},
            overrides={},
        )
        t.execute(context)


job_list = make_list("{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='get_input', key='return_value') }}")

run_this >> job_list
```

For Airflow >= 2.3.0 :
You can use Dynamic Task, which create number of task dynamically according to parameter in the execution.

```
@task
def make_list(count):
    return [i for i in range(count)]


job_list = make_list("{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='get_input', key='return_value') }}")
batch = BatchOperator.partial(
    task_id="submit_batch_job",
    job_name=JOB_NAME,
    job_queue=JOB_QUEUE,
    job_definition=JOB_DEFINITION,
    parameters={}
).expand(job_id=job_list)

run_this >> job_list >> batch
```

also, be notice that num_jobs is str unless you set in your Dag that "render_template_as_native_obj=True". if you don't then you just need to cast it : int(count)

Comment: Note: Dynamic Task Mapping was introduced in Airflow 2.3.0. However, MWAA currently only supports up to Airflow 2.2.0.

Comment: Note: You can use `airflow.models.xcom_arg.XComArg` to simplify the last two lines to just `job_list = make_list(XComArg(run_this))`